# Editing custom styles via VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm trying to set a custom style for which I can change the number format based on a user selection i.e. may be USD, GBP, EUR or a number of others.

Is this even possible?

I was trying to achieve it via VBA and an on change of cell routine doing something like this:

```
Style("StyleName").NumberFormat = Range("ChosenCell").NumberFormat
```

The idea being that the style will then impact the whole workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was nearly there anyway:

```
ThisWorkbook.Styles("StyleName").NumberFormat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("ChosenCell").NumberFormat
```